# RMarkdown conversion

Tags: r, r-markdown

````
---
title: "Twitter Data processing"
author: "Ankur"
date: "7 September 2016"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(SnowballC)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
```
````

"SnowballC" is required for stemming the document in this particualr verion. You may alternatively need "Snowball".

````
```{r Turning into Corpus, include=TRUE, warning=FALSE}
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus, stemDocument)
writeLines(strwrap(myCorpus[[250]]$content,60))
```
````

I am having issues while knitting the RMD Document. the code works fine but it is not building the RMD file. I have the "myCorpus" variable in other file, butr it is loaded into an environment. I am having the following error:

```
Error in tm-map(myCorpus, stemDocument) : object ;myCorpus'  not found  
calls:<Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval-> eval ->tm_map Execution Halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to load the data "myCorpus" to your .RMD file:

1. `library(knitr)
    knit('your_file.Rmd')`

   This will take your recent environment into account and the error should be gone.
2. Store your "myCorpus" as "myCorpus.RData" and load it manually in your RMD file

   ````
   ```{r load myCorpus, include=FALSE}
    load("myCorpus.RData")
   ````

   If you do it this way you can use the "knit" button from RStudio.

I hope one of this ways is a good solution for you.